# How do you schedule cron jobs for multiple dates?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

I would like to know if this is correct.

I want to schedule a cron job for multiple dates such as:

- 7 Dec 2016
- 14 Jan 2017
- 21 Feb 2017

`30 9 7,14,21 12,1,2 * my_awesome_script...`

While I could wait for the next date to see if it works...I just don't want to :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no common pattern, it is worth using three different lines:

```
0 0  7 12 * your_awesome_script
0 0 14  1 * your_awesome_script
0 0 21  2 * your_awesome_script
```

You could try to get a complex syntax taking advantage of the day of the week, etc, but it would get quite difficult to understand.

Remember the format:

```
 +---------------- minute (0 - 59)
 |  +------------- hour (0 - 23)
 |  |  +---------- day of month (1 - 31)
 |  |  |  +------- month (1 - 12)
 |  |  |  |  +---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
 |  |  |  |  |
 *  *  *  *  *  command to be executed
```